# Cypher query to return path with specific relationship types

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher, graph-databases

I've set up a Neo4j Graph DB.

And I've the following Nodes and Relationship Types:

[image: Left panel - Database Information]

My question is how I get the Path between 2 Nodes from Station only with relationship type "BUS"?

```
Station(1)->BUS->Station(31)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple Cypher query like this:

```
MATCH p = (:Station {id:1})-[:BUS*]->(:Station {id:31})
RETURN p
```

This query will `MATCH` the path (`p`) between `(:Station{id:1})` and `(:Station {id:31})` following only relationships of type `:BUS` with any length (denoted by the `*` after the relationship type).

You can also specify the number of hops the query will follow, putting it after the `*`(Example: [:BUS*1..3] will follow at least 1 and at most 3 hops). Take a look in the [MATCH clause docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/).

**EDIT:**

From Hans comment:

> I am interested in the shortest path

You can use [shortestPath()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path) function. This way:

```
MATCH (a:Station {id:1}), (b:Station {id:31}), p = shortestPath((a)-[*]-(b))
WHERE ALL (r IN relationships(p) WHERE type(r) = 'BUS')
RETURN p
```

From the docs:

> Predicates used in the **WHERE** clause that apply to the shortest path
>   pattern are evaluated before deciding what the shortest matching path
>   is.

The query above will return the shortest path between `a` and `b` evaluating only `:BUS` relationships.

Comment: This doenst work it loads and loads and loads.. (like 20minutes) no doesnt return a result

Comment: Hmm... Have you a big graph? And if you specify a hop interval (like `[:BUS*1..3]`)?

Comment: That is: is not it a problem related with the size of your graph (loads and loads and loads...)?

Comment: If i do [:BUS*1..3] i get (no changes, no records).. but there is a Path..

Comment: You know what is the path size between station 1 and station 31?

Comment: No, i don't know

Comment: You can share your graph with us? maybe I can reproduce your scenario here.

Comment: How should I share?

Comment: You can upload your data folder and edit the question putting on it a link to download the uploaded folder.

Comment: Do you need all paths between the stations using that relationship, or are you only interested in a limited number of paths?

Comment: I am interested in the shortest path

Comment: Works THANK YOU!